# error ctypes OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found

Tags: python, ctypes

Module for my program use eyeD3 which use ctypes. While running I got this error:

```
  File "D:\code\git2\LyricsGrabber\MA lyrics", line 8, in <module>
    import eyed3
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\eyed3\__init__.py", line 35, in <module>
    from .utils.log import log                                            # noqa
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\eyed3\utils\__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
    import magic
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\magic.py", line 154, in <module>
    libmagic = ctypes.CDLL(dll)
  File "C:\Users\..\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\ctypes\__init__.py", line 348, in __init__
    self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found
```

I searched same questions on stackoverflow and got that some dlls are missing. Do everything that decribed here:https://github.com/ahupp/python-magic#dependencies
Drop dlls in windows/System32 and write file_name in Magic class. It still doesn't work.
Also I check for:

```
import sys
import os
print(os.path.exists('C:\\Windows\\System32\\libmagic-1.dll'))
```

and it returns False. I suspect this is the problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: So is the DLL actually there?

Comment: Yes, all needed dlls are in in system32 folder

Comment: If Python can't find the DLL using the `os` module then you have a broader problem. I'm guessing your Python process doesn't have permission to view the system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. I solved it by installing this VCL Player Version
https://get.videolan.org/vlc/3.0.3/win64/vlc-3.0.3-win64.exe
then uninstalling and reinstalling the python-vlc package. Hope this may help you as well